# Pass function argument to string groovy file Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uploads data to S3. The S3 destination should be different depending on whether the branch is master or not. So far I have tried this within the `build.groovy` file:

```
import lib.Constants
def s3Deploy() {
    script {
        if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            s3Deploy_func('codebase')
        }
        else {
            s3Deploy_func('new_codebase')
        }
    }
}

def s3Deploy_func(String s3_folder) {
    sh '''
    aws s3 cp "$WORKSPACE/" s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/$s3_folder --profile ${PROFILE} --recursive
    '''
}

return this
```

The variables Workspace, bucket_name and profile are successfully overwritten. However, s3_folder always is empty. I have tried with `${s3_folder}` as well and it still the same. How could I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is the variable empty or null? This could also help: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I think it should use double quote `"""` instead of `'''`, and `${s3_folder}` instead of `{s3_folder}`.

So the fix should be

```
sh """
aws s3 cp "$WORKSPACE/" s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${s3_folder} --profile ${PROFILE} --recursive
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The double quotes don't modify the results. I also had tried ${s3_folder} and the variable is null instead of "new_codebase" and "codebase"

Comment: Emm, `null` is very strange, it means the variable substitution has taken place, but with the wrong value instead of the one you pass.